# Meteor package working on browser but not on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

There's no problem using the Meteor package `strikeout:string.js` on the client side (browser JS console), but it throws an error when using it on the server side.

Checked [`package.js`](https://github.com/strikeout/meteor-string.js/blob/master/package.js) and found `api.addFiles('lib/string.js', ['client','server']);`, is this not sufficient?

**Test code**

```
console.log(S('jon').capitalize().s)
```

**Error on server**

```
ReferenceError: S is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this not sufficient? **YES**, you are getting the Reference because you are not requiring it.

In order to use it on the server, you should require it, on this example im using [meteorhacks:npm](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm).

It was not possible for me create a Meteorpad of this, so i will do here step-by-step.

**First** `meteor add meteor hacks:npm`

**Second** On the recent create packages.json add this line

```
{
  "string": "3.1.0"
}
```

**Third** Now just add the server code.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    var S = Meteor.npmRequire('string'); //server side
    console.log(S('jon').capitalize().s)
  });
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
I20150326-10:54:05.639(-5)? Jon
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Tried your suggestion and I get the error `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: @Nyxynyx just update the answer, i made it work on my computer